# how to list selected items from database in a table of two columns in php?

Tags: php, mysql

So here's what I basically want to do.
I have display a list of members and each of them have a check box next to it.

Just like this:

[  ] Spongebob

[  ] Patrick

[  ] Squidward

[  ] Sandy

[  ] Mr. Krab

[ OK ]

Whenever I select a number of members, and click OK, it will lead to a print page. In that print page, I want the members to be listed in two columns like this:

---

Spongebob | Patrick |

Squidward | Sandy   |

Mr. Krab  |

So far, I've only done it to be in a single column.

Here is my current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

$check_list = $_POST['check_list']; 
foreach ($check_list as $selected){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addmember WHERE id = '".$selected."' ORDER BY id");

$limit = 2;
$count = 0;

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $name = $row ['name'];

    if ($count < $limit){

        if ($count == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
            }

            echo "<td>$name";
        }else{
            $count = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr><td>
            $name</td><tr>";
            }
            $count++;
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
        }

        echo '<script>window.print();</script>';
        }
    else{

    echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one member.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>";
    }
}
```

Any suggestion and advice is very appreciated.. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to add your code. Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for how to.

Comment: thank you @ReneKorss ! :)  Now I have my code displayed. It's my first time posting to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your while is not necessary, because you only need one row. You have overcomplicated things a bit.

You need to check

- If `$count` is 0 - start row
- If `$count == $limit` or is last item of all - end row

And thats it. Between just echo `<td>` with `$name`.

So try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

    $check_list = $_POST['check_list'];

    $itemsCount = count($check_list);
    $limit = 2;
    $count = $doneCount = 0;

    echo "<table>";

    foreach ($check_list as $selected){
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addmember WHERE id = '".$selected."' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

      $name = $row['name'];

      // Start new row
      if ($count == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
      }

      // Echo name
      echo "<td>".$name."</td>";

      // End row, increment counters
      if (++$count == $limit || $itemsCount == ++$doneCount ){
        $count = 0;
        echo "</tr>";
      }

    }

    echo "</tr></table>";

    echo '<script>window.print();</script>';
  }
  else{
    echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one member.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>";
  }
}
```

`++$count` increments by one and then returns it, so we compare and increment all in one. See [PHP: Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, cause they are deprecated. Instead use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**Futher reading:**

- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you so much @Rene Korss !! I tested your code and it works perfectly!! I cannot thank you enough. I'm literally crying right now. Thanks! :')